# Fancybox 3 change link title to data-caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-3

I would like to ask you if there is any javascript method to grab link title and use it or change it to data-caption in fancybox 3? The only condition is if the link title exists.

This is what I have now:

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" title="some-title" href="big_1.jpg">
<img src="small_1.jpg">
</a>
```

and I would like to somehow change it to this:

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="some-title" href="big_1.jpg">
<img src="small_1.jpg">
</a>
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attr. Note that you will need to execute the logic to set the `data-caption` attribute *before* you instantiate the fancybox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use some JS code to do

```js
jQuery(function(){
$('a[data-fancybox="gallery"]').each(function(){
 if($(this).attr('title') != '' ){
  $(this).attr('data-caption', $(this).attr('title'));
 }
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" title="some-title" href="big_1.jpg">
<img src="small_1.jpg">
</a>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" title="title" href="big_1.jpg">
<img src="small_1.jpg">
</a>
<a data-fancybox="gallery"  href="big_1.jpg">
<img src="small_1.jpg">
</a>
```